# Java spring webflow. Tomcat can't find view file

Tags: java, spring-webflow

I have big problem. When i do apply to web flow by id, it goes into it but later view state returns 404 Error. Flow xml file is in jar. Jar file is loaded on execution, but i cant understand why cannot find path to view file.

Comment: Are you sure you are asking about *swing* and not *spring* web flow?

Comment: Please check the logs to see what error message have been logged. Are you able to access app by http://localhost:8080/myapp ?

Comment: Yes. Everything works fine. And other flow works fine. But this new one not. It going to the flow and action bean, which are in jar file, but when goes to view state : view="folder/admin/viewFile.xhtml" then show 404 error

Answer (score 0):

If tomcat cannot find a view file the view is not there. So, check where is it. Take a look on error message. It will help. And fix you project structure. This behavior can be controlled by `InternalResourceViewResolver`. Here is the configuration fragment I took from application I am working on.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```